# Website randomly loads slowly every once in a while

Tags: laravel, apache

I have a laravel website which is running on apache2 and it's running on multiple servers for multiple clients. There is only one web server where the website loads slowly. Now it's not loading slowly on every page load, it randomly loads slowly. Also after loading a page, that has loaded quickly, if you leave the site for say 5 minutes and begin to navigate to another page, the page loads slowly yet again.

Not sure if in fact it's apache that causes the slowness of the site, or if it's a third party plugin because as the page is loading it mentions m.stripe.com is loading and then on another page load, it could be another plugin loading.

Are there any tools that I can use to decipher this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there where 2 A name records with different IP adresses for the same domain. I would have thought some error would have been raised by apache because of this, but it randomly selected the ip to serve the site and of course long load times for the ip that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer why a Laravel website is slower. There are many reasons behind a slower Laravel application. You have to debug and take decisions where you need to improve in your application. Here a list I focus on when I develop an application.

1. `Database`

How may database query load on each page? you have to ensure any recursive query not exist. Make efficient data cache. Check queries takes a little time to execute.

2. `Network Connection`

If you are using different network connections with your Redis, database, queue then make sure those connections are well optimized and taking a little time to connect and serve data.

3. `Cache Files`

Make Cache you blade HTML files, routers, config files, and optimize those cache. Also, reduct autoloads services as much as possible.

4. `Optimize your Images`

Optimize your images. I recommend not to use local files. try to use a cloud service.

5. `Minify CSS and JS file`

You should minify your CSS and js files. and try to use libraries from CDN.

6. `Use Queue`

Use queue where possible like email send, PDF Generate...

Answer (score 0):

1. **Minify** your HTML, CSS, and Javascript. it's a great way to increase page spread. Depending on the IDE you use, you could install a minifier extension, use webpack to bundle your code, or use an online minifier like https://fixcode.org/minify
2. Use a CDN to load static files like scripts, images, and style sheet. you could also load all of your site via a CDN
3. you could also consider lazy loading parts of your script. especially in cases where you compile scripts with webpack